# Set table view into editing mode

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` and have added an edit button from code rather than IB. This comes with `UITableViewControllers` but not UIVCs. How can I get this button to put the table view into editing mode in swift? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
class WordsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create `rightBarButtonItem` as below with an action.

In `viewDidLoad()` :

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("showEditing:"))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

and then make a function like,

```
 func showEditing(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
 {
    if(self.tableView.isEditing == true)
    {
        self.tableView.isEditing = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Done"   
    }
    else
    {
        self.tableView.isEditing = true
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit" 
    }
}
```

Make sure, `:` is appended to function name in `Selector` of action in `viewDidLoad`
Hope it helps!

Comment: many thanks @iRealMe :-). How do you get it to show Done once pressed so it can then take the table out of edit mode?

Comment: @richc Updated my answer!

Comment: This distinction of cases is why you should just use the built in `editButtonItem`.

Comment: In your viewWillAppear() override func, just call the func of showEditing(nil). You should update this function with optional bar button.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a solution for **Swift 4.2**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // Use the edit button provided by the view controller.
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    // Takes care of toggling the button's title.
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)

    // Toggle table view editing.
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
}
```

The view controller's `setEditing` is called by default when the `editButtonItem` is pressed. By default, pressing the button toggles its title between "Edit" and "Done", so calling `super.setEditing` takes care of that for us, and we use the `tableView`'s `setEditing` method to toggle the editing state of the table view.

Sources:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621471-editbuttonitem
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621378-setediting
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614876-setediting

Comment: If this ViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController, super.setEditing() will call tableView.setEditing for you.

Comment: This is the best solution according to the documentation, is using editButtonItem instead of creating a new button item and also is receiving the message in setEditing(_:animated:) method instead of creating a new one. I just have one concern: why are you inverting the value of isEditing ?? I think just passing the value "as is" is enough (super.setEditing(editing, animated: true))

Comment: @LeoGalante The value of `tableView.isEditing` needs to be inverted because we are toggling it. If it's editing currently, then we want it to stop editing. If it's not editing currently, then we want it to start editing. If we didn't invert it, then it would never get changed.

Comment: hi @JaredCleghorn, i'm not sure about that, I already tried without the inversion and worked well, looks like the `editing` param we receive in the `setEditing` method is already inverted.

Comment: @LeoGalante Ah, it seems we may have talked past each other a bit. In my answer, I make use of the objects’ `isEditing` *properties*, where as you are referring to the method’s `editing` *parameter*. The former does have to be inverted because it simply stores the current state of the object, while the latter, as you say, is “already inverted”. I seems like both approaches should produce the same result in almost all situations, but I think you are right that using `editing` is simpler, so I will update my answer accordingly. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 3 & 4** answer that IMHO is **better** than other answers:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(toggleEditing)) // create a bat button
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton // assign button
}

@objc private func toggleEditing() {
    listTableView.setEditing(!listTableView.isEditing, animated: true) // Set opposite value of current editing status
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = listTableView.isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit" // Set title depending on the editing status
}
```

**Why** do I think it's **better**:

1. Fewer code lines.
2. Bar button is initialized once but not every time you press the button.

Answer (score 8):

Call this method on button click.

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Or if you want it to work like a toggle use

```
tableView.setEditing(!tableView.editing, animated: true)
```

I assume you have a button, which calls `editButtonPressed` on press. So implementation of this method could look like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("editButtonPressed"))
}

func editButtonPressed(){
  tableView.setEditing(!tableView.editing, animated: true) 
  if tableView.editing == true{
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("editButtonPressed"))
  }else{
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("editButtonPressed"))
  }
}
```

This also changes title of the bar button.

Answer (score 3):

Override the view controller's `-setEditing:animated:`, call super, and call the same method on your table view.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: I don't know Swift syntax, I can only post it in Objective-C.

Comment: i don't know ObjC so i'll have to let someone else vote for your answer! Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 2):

First :

```
let editButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showEditing(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton
```

Then :

```
  @objc func showEditing(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
 {
    if(self.tableView.isEditing == true)
    {
        self.tableView.isEditing = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit"
    }
    else
    {
        self.tableView.isEditing = true
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Done"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 version of njuri post:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PackageNameLabel.text = detailPackageName
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(PackageDetailsTableViewController.editButtonPressed))

}


func editButtonPressed(){
    tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
    if tableView.isEditing == true{
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(PackageDetailsTableViewController.editButtonPressed))
    }else{
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(PackageDetailsTableViewController.editButtonPressed))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. But for me it only works if I add @objc in front of the func editButtonPressed(). Maybe this could be updated in your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You only need 1 line of code in `viewDidLoad()` to get edit button and its related functionality.

`navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem`